# Constructing an infeasible primal linear program whose dual is also infeasible.

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I could come up with an example where the linear program in infeasible and its dual is unbounded but I cannot create an example where the 2 of them are infeasible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not a specific problem. I rather want an example to convince myself of the claim.